# how to get length of keyword-only argument?

Tags: python, discord

generally - i was trying to make `if len(arg) < 1:` ofcourse didnt worked (only when more than one arg it was working), when i made `(ctx, *args)` instead of `(ctx *, arg)` it was almost working but was also adding some more characters (just it wasnt throwing out `test` but `('test'),` somehow). how to make it work? without added symbols and not messing up with removing **all** symbols? full current code here:

```py
@bot.command()
async def cowsay(ctx, *, arg):
  if len(arg) < 1:
    url = 'https://icanhazdadjoke.com/'
    joke = requests.get(url, headers={"Accept":'application/json '}).json()
    await ctx.send(f" \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\n < {joke['joke']} > \n ------------- \n        \\      ^\_\_^ \n          \\    (oo)\\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ \n                (\_\_)\\             )\\/\\ \n                        \|\|-------w \| \n                        \|\|              \|\|" )
  else:
    await ctx.send(f" \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\n < {arg} > \n ------------- \n        \\      ^\_\_^ \n          \\    (oo)\\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ \n                (\_\_)\\             )\\/\\ \n                        \|\|-------w \| \n                        \|\|              \|\|" )
```

PS: discord officially didnt said what to do with `*, arg` as shown here : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments

Comment: This function only accepts 2 arguments, one of them has to be passed as a keyword argument. What do you mean by `len(arg)` ?

Comment: how much characters/words/anything are? i was just trying to get if message have anything more than command and just put this somewhere in reply...

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is detect if any arg was passed to the command, you can just check `args` length:

```
@bot.command()
async def cowsay(ctx, *args):
  if not args:
    url = 'https://icanhazdadjoke.com/'
    joke = requests.get(url, headers={"Accept":'application/json '}).json()
    await ctx.send("string_without_args")
  else:
    await ctx.send(f"string_with_{args}")
```

Comment: Im not going to use `*args` im going to use `*, arg` And with `*, arg` doesnt work